# How can a program create a file and know the path (which was randomly specified by the user) to the file after reopening the program later?

Tags: c++

Just want to know the principle of that and how that could work. If my program asked to enter a path to where the file was to be saved and then when I restart the program instead of asking for the path again, it would naturally know where the file was saved, so it could do further file manipulation.

Comment: you would need to store that information somewhere, probably in another file.

Answer (score 3):

Well how does your brain do that? It remembers.
How does it remember? By storing it somewhere.
You need to do the same in your program.

The most idiomatic way depends on your OS.

On linux you could store it in a config file in the users home directory.

On windows you could use a registry entry to store that information.

Then on start you retrieve that and done.